# How should the children be taught to be wary of online predators?

Tags: safety, age-appropriate

Online predators can be known people as well as unknown.

What does the child need to know before going online to stop being a prey?

Comment: I've voted to close this question as at this time it doesn't contain enough information to provide a genuinely useful answer.  If an edit can provide useful (and more specific) information then I'll be happy to review it.

Comment: @JamesSnell what more information should be added?

Comment: Their age, what they plan to use the internet for, how responsible/trusting you believe them to be, what your neighbourhood is like, how much time you spend with them, the kind of other kids they hang out with, what you're comfortable talking about with them; there's a lot of stuff...

Basically, there are a lot of general answers we can give, but those are trivially googlable. If it's not for a specific child and just a general question, then more a more specific case would still be helpful.

Comment: @deworde How can I answer those questions right now?  Child is 2.9 years old right now.  The reason I have put age-appropriate tag is that I don't know at what  age  all this should  be started.  What information do you think I should add now?

Comment: This is a really great article you should read http://www.kidsmartz.org/StrangerDanger

Comment: @paradigmBreaking The kind of information that would make this question better would be something that makes it at least somewhat less broad.  For example, what kinds of things do you plan on letting your child do online?  Eg: knowing how to deal with people via some kind of chat (like in games like Minecraft) is a different ball game than dealing with people via Facebook.  What (and how) you teach an 8 year old is different than a 13 year old.  Give us a general idea about these things.  (You can also ask multiple separate questions if there are more than one area you want help with.)

Answer (score 4):

How you tell them depends on their age, but the key messages to get over are:

- There are bad people on the Internet. Some of them like to hurt children. They are like bullies who never grew up.
- You can meet off-line friends on-line, but be careful what you say in chatrooms where other people might be listening.
- Some people on the Internet lie about who they are. Sometimes they pretend to be children like you in order to trick you. Be friendly, but always remember that they might not be telling the truth.
- Never tell anyone you meet on-line your name (use a handle), your age or where you live or go to school. Its OK to say what country you live in.
- Never send anyone a picture of you. Not even if they send you a picture of them.
- If anyone starts being nasty to you on-line, tell a grown-up.
- If anyone starts asking naughty/sexual questions, or shows you naughty/sexual pictures, tell a grown-up.
- If anyone you meet on-line wants to meet in the real world, tell a grown-up.

Answer (score 0):

Don’t say: Never talk to strangers.
Say: You should not approach just anyone. If you need help, look for a uniformed police officer, a store clerk with a nametag, or a parent with children.

Don’t say: Stay away from people you don’t know.
Say: It’s important for you to get my permission before going anywhere with anyone.

Don’t say: You can tell someone is bad just by looking at them.
Say: Pay attention to what people do. Tell me right away if anyone asks you to keep a secret, makes you feel uncomfortable, or tries to get you to go with them.

Comment: This asks about *online* predators. Your response is more in keeping with real life strangers. :-)